# Export data from Data table to Excel

Tags: export-to-excel

I have a data table with **49000 rows and 300 columns data**. How to export complete data into single excel?
I tried the links below but `file created with 396MB memory, file unable to open`.

1. http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support/articles/asp-net-excel.
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/322964/DataSet-to-Excel-File-Conversion-using-ExcelLibrar
3. http://exportdata.codeplex.com/

**I need a solution to create the excel with less memory(mail attached file size) and open the file** , Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change file extension .xls to .csv
export large data also.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to create the file with mail attached file size but you can use compression methods like 7-zip or tar.gz2 to get the max compression size.

I hope this helps you.